# updating a subdocument inside nested array using $addToset followed by $pull

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
{"layers":[{"layer name":"layer1","layer_vals":[{"name":"val1","updated":"value"}]}]}
```

I have a JSON document like the one above.I wish to change the value of updated everytime an operation is performed on that subdocument.As can be seen the document is nested  inside two arrays.I am planning to use a $addToSet to first add the new updated value and then do $pull to remove the old one.But I am getting an error saying I cannot perform both operation on same document.Is there any solution to this?
Also any other suggestions on solving the above problem would be great too

Comment: check this out https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting an error saying I cannot perform both operation on same document.Is there any solution to this?

No. As of MongoDB 3.0 you can only use one operator like `$push`, `$addToSet`, or `$pop` on an array field in a single update. There's a bunch of related JIRA issues for things like this, but perhaps [SERVER-1050](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1050) is the closest.

Glancing at your schema, it looks like you might be better served by having a document per layer

```
{ "name" : "layer1", "parent" : "some reference", "vals" : [{ "name" : "val1", "updated" : "value" }] }
```

possibly with a reference `parent` to the document where the `layer` field lived. You will run into situations where it's difficult to query on `layer_vals` given that it's a nested array.